# Можно ли создать суперглобальную переменную в PHP?

Tags: php

То есть не создать элемент в одном из суперглобальных массивов, а создать свою переменную.

Comment: только использовав `$GLOBALS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если штуки три, то такая модель вам подойдет, думаю

```
class MyClass1 {
  static $instance = null;
  private $vars = array();
  function check() { if (self::$instance == null) self::$instance = new self; };
  function set($name, $val) {
    self::check();
    self::$instance->_set($name, $val);
    echo "\n".$name.' = '.$val;
    return false;
  }
  function _set($n, $v) { $this->vars[$n] = $v; }
}
function myFunc() {
  MyClass::set('a', 1);
  return false;
}
myFunc();
```

Comment: Ох, спасибо! Это я затупил.
В принципе, я обойдусь и просто функцией. Я же забыл, что функции то сами видны везде. Так что я могу обернуть в функцию нужные мне вещи)
Думаю, как мне будет красивей, `$GLOBALS` или через функцию.  
А жаль, что суперглобальные переменные нельзя.

Comment: По-моему то ли в 5.3, то ли в 5.4 появился такая возможность:

    function myLog() {
      if (empty($GLOBALS['myClass']))
        $GLOBALS['myClass'] = new myClass;
      return $GLOBALS['myClass'];
    } 
    myLog()->log();

Может, заинтересует)

А вообще если б можно было создавать суперглобалы, кол-во быдлокода возросло бы еще больше)

Comment: @Sh4dow, а что именно тут появилось в 5.3/5.4? `return` объекта?

Comment: @Sh4dow о kiss походу не слышал :D К чему такое извращение?

Comment: @Construct, нет, цепочки вызовов а ля jquery) Могу врать, мож раньше, помню, что на php3/4 такую штуку я не смог сделать, хотя идея была))

Во всяком случае мне выдавало что-то вроде "unexpected object operator"

@AlexWindHope эээм вполне вероятно, что не слышал)

Comment: Попробовал этот способ - ничего не получается. Как только я перехожу на другую страницу, значение $instance и $vars обнуляются

Answer (score 3):

Нет, в PHP нету способа создавать свои суперглобальные переменные, да и не нужно это. Есть много подходов в которых глобальные переменные не нужны, да и вообще, глобальные переменные - зло :)

Вы лучше опишите задачу для которой вам потребовались свои суперглобальные переменные.

Comment: ...и решите ее синглтоном. Что-то мне подсказывает)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ясно.  
Насчёт задачи:  
мне только штуки три нужны были их.  
Объекты-логи, для удобного логирования абсолютно из любого места приложения. Сейчас использую `$GLOBALS`, это тоже нормально, только подлинней.

Comment: @Shadow, там, в принципе, и есть синглтон.

Comment: .

    class Log {
      public static function read(){}
      public static function wright(){}
    }

    Log::read();
    Log::wright();

Осталось только реализовать логику

Comment: @AlexWindHope, хм, а это тоже интересно!  
У меня был объект (просто я там создавал из класса `Log` три объекта для разных файлов лога, типа^
    $log->write() // для основного лога
    $log_hack->write() // для лога попыток несанкц-го доступа
Можно и так, то есть тогда либо передавая в переменной, в какой лог писать, либо создав разные классы.

Comment: Создайте, например, базовый класс `LogBase` все остальные логи наследуйте от него.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, та же мысль была уже, только я придумал `baseLog` :D

Comment: Помогите разобраться, похожая ситуация. Нужно сохранять некоторые данные (то есть например некоторые параметры, сохранять выбранные пользователем галочки или опции) в том случае, когда мы обновляем страницу или уходим на другую страницу. require_once не помогает, обновляю страницу - и данные стираются. А как сделать, чтобы при обновлении страницы галочки сохранялись на своих местах, то есть как создать такую закулисную переменную, данные в которой сохраняются независимо от того, что мы покинули или обновили страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Ну если вы имете ввиду переменную, которая будет сохранять своё значение даже после перезагрузки страницы, то вам сессии в самый раз подойдут. Работать с ними очень легко.

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду переменную, которая по умолчанию будет видна во всех областях видимости.
Как раз типа массива `$_SESSION`, который сам такой переменной является.

Comment: А почему $_SESSION не подходит. Поверьте, это лучшее решение.

Comment: Может быть константа? Тогда функция [define()](http://www.php.su/functions/?define)

Comment: @Deonis, к сожалению, мне надо объект.

Comment: Ну попробуйте $_GLOBALS :

http://www.php.ru/manual/ini.core.html#ini.register-globals

Comment: @Asen, подходит (правда, не `$_SESSION` уж тогда, а `$GLOBALS`).
Просто мне стало интересно, существует ли в PHP способ создания суперглобальной переменной. Не иные способы решения моей задачи, а конкретно это).  
`$GLOBALS` я как раз и использую.

Comment: okay, если ответ устраивает, то примите его пожалуйста =)

Comment: @Asen, пока что мне не ответили ещё.  
Точно нету способа?